# Read Parquet file stored in S3 with AWS Lambda (Python 3)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to load, process and write Parquet files in S3 with AWS Lambda. My testing / deployment process is:

- https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda as a container to mock the Amazon environment, because of the native libraries that need to be installed (numpy amongst others).
- This procedure to generate a zip file: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python
- Add a test python function to the zip, send it to S3, update the lambda and test it

It seems that there are two possible approaches, **which both work locally to the docker container**:

1. fastparquet with s3fs: Unfortunately the unzipped size of the package is bigger than 256MB and therefore I can't update the Lambda code with it.
2. pyarrow with s3fs: I followed https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/916 and when executed with the lambda function I get either:

   - *If I prefix the URI with S3 or S3N* (as in the code example): In the Lambda environment `OSError: Passed non-file path: s3://mybucket/path/to/myfile` in pyarrow/parquet.py, line 848. Locally I get `IndexError: list index out of range` in pyarrow/parquet.py, line 714
   - *If I don't prefix the URI with S3 or S3N*: It works locally (I can read the parquet data). In the Lambda environment, I get the same `OSError: Passed non-file path: s3://mybucket/path/to/myfile` in pyarrow/parquet.py, line 848.

My questions are  :

- why do I get a different result in my docker container than I do in the Lambda environment?
- what is the proper way to give the URI?
- is there an accepted way to read Parquet files in S3 through AWS Lambda?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

AWS has a project ([AWS Data Wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler)) that allows it with full Lambda Layers support.

In the Docs there is a [step-by-step](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#aws-lambda-layer) to do it.

Code example:

```
import awswrangler as wr

# Write
wr.s3.to_parquet(
    dataframe=df,
    path="s3://...",
    dataset=True,
    database="my_database",  # Optional, only with you want it available on Athena/Glue Catalog
    table="my_table",
    partition_cols=["PARTITION_COL_NAME"])

# READ
df = wr.s3.read_parquet(path="s3://...")
```

[Reference](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to accomplish writing parquet files into S3 using fastparquet. It's a little tricky but my breakthrough came when I realized that to put together all the dependencies, I had to use the same exact Linux that Lambda is using.

Here's how I did it:

### 1. Spin up a EC2 instance using the Amazon Linux image that is used with Lambda

Source:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html

Linux image:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home#Images:visibility=public-images;search=amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2

Note: you might need to install many packages and change python version to 3.6 as this Linux is not meant for development. Here's how I looked for packages:

```
sudo yum list | grep python3
```

I installed:

```
python36.x86_64
python36-devel.x86_64
python36-libs.x86_64
python36-pip.noarch
python36-setuptools.noarch
python36-tools.x86_64
```

### 2. Used the instructions from here to built a zip file with all of the dependencies that my script would use with dumping them all in a folder and the zipping them with this command:

```
mkdir parquet
cd parquet
pip install -t . fastparquet 
pip install -t . (any other dependencies)
copy my python file in this folder
zip and upload into Lambda
```

Note: there are some constraints I had to work around: Lambda doesn't let you upload zip larger 50M and unzipped > 260M. If anyone knows a better way to get dependencies into Lambda, please do share.

Source:
[Write parquet from AWS Kinesis firehose to AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430535/write-parquet-from-aws-kinesis-firehose-to-aws-s3/46525856#46525856)

Comment: For many-linux variant of pyarrow, If you keep all the *16 files only, get rid of the other larger copy for each lib and then repackage them into a zip file, the lambda package size comes under 250 which the AWS lambda accepts

Answer (score 2):

This was an environment issue (Lambda in VPC not getting access to the bucket). Pyarrow is now working.
Hopefully the question itself will give a good-enough overview on how to make all that work.

Comment: Could you provide any more info on how you got this working? I keep running into an ImportError even though the pyarrow package is in my zip. It keeps saying `pyarrow is required for parquet support` I am running on Python 2.7 so that could be the issue.

Comment: It might be, but it's difficult to diagnose without context. Your error does not look like an ModuleNotFoundError or ImportError though. I followed the links I gave to create my env.
Roughly:
`docker run -it lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 bash

mkdir lambda

cd lambda
virtualenv ~/lambda
source ~/lambda/bin/activate
pip install pyarrow
pip install pandas
pip install s3fs
cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages
zip -r9 ~/lambda.zip .
[get the lambda.zip locally]
zip -ur ../lambda.zip lambda_function.py`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ptah. I took a guess that it was an incompatibility with the Python 2.7 runtime in AWS Lambda and I was right. Once I upgraded the code to run on 3.6 and built the upgraded zip file `pyarrow` worked without a problem. Hopefully this helps others who run into this.

Comment: Could you give us a sample of the code? I wonder how are you writing the files and using the s3fs object... I'm trying with pyarrow.parquet.write_table() but it's not happening for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One can also achieve this through the [AWS sam cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install.html) and Docker (we'll explain this requirement later).

**1.Create a directory and initialize sam**

```
mkdir some_module_layer
cd some_module_layer
sam init
```

by typing the last command a series of three question would be prompted. One could choose the following series of answers (I'm considering working under Python3.7, but other options are possible).

> 1 - AWS Quick  Start Templates
>
> 8 - Python 3.7
>
> Project name [sam-app]: some_module_layer
>
> 1 - Hello World Example

**2. Modify requirements.txt file**

```
cd some_module_layer
vim hello_world/requirements.txt
```

this will open `requirements.txt` file on vim, on Windows you could type instead `code hello_world/requirements.txt` to edit the file on Visual Studio Code.

**3. Add pyarrow to requirements.txt**

Alongside pyarrow, it will work to include additionnaly `pandas` and `s3fs`. In this case including pandas will avoid it to not recognize `pyarrow` as an engine to read parquet files.

```
pandas
pyarrow
s3fs
```

**4. Build with a container**

Docker is required to use the option `--use-container` when running the `sam build` command. If it's the first time, it will pull the `lambci/lambda:build-python3.7` Docker  image.

```
sam build --use-container
rm .aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction/app.py
rm .aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction/__init__.py
rm .aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction/requirements.txt
```

notice that we're keeping only the python libraries.

**5. Zip files**

```
cp -r .aws-sam/build/HelloWorldFunction/ python/
zip -r some_module_layer.zip python/
```

On Windows, it would work to run  `Compress-Archive python/ some_module_layer.zip`.

**6. Upload zip file to AWS**

The following [link](https://medium.com/@adhorn/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-for-python-6e10b1f9a5d) is useful for this.

Comment: Can you run these commands on mac OS or does this approach need to be run on a Linux machine?

Comment: @Powers, they work on Mac, Linux and Windows. Are you getting any errors?