# AWS lambda Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named PIL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-imaging-library, amazon-rekognition

I am using a lambda function of `SearchFacesbyimage`  And I am using this doc   `https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-your-own-face-recognition-service-using-amazon-rekognition/`

where for comparison I am using this

```
from PIL import Image
```

And I am getting this error
 `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named PIL`

Comment: Did you install all the dependencies, compressed to .zip file and then uploaded to lambda??

Comment: @ManojAcharya  I tried to search But didnt get solution. can you guide  where I have to install ?  I am not running that In local .

Comment: Please refer to this link once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50711722/how-to-upload-python-code-with-libraries-to-aws-lambda-from-windows-local-machin/50723859?noredirect=1#comment88471390_50723859

Comment: thanks for reply. Can you tell what will have  lambda_function.py ? as my lambda function is ImageComp.py  . So what things I need to change ?

Comment: And 2nd thing how I can upload zip file to lambda directly  ?

Comment: First create a lambda function from console. Now under Code entry type inside Function Code section, select Upload a .zip file. Also you can simply rename your python file to lambda_function.py....or change the handler inside the function code to ImageComp.lambda_handler. Note "lambda_handler" is the function which will be called when the lambda function is triggered.

Comment: @ManojAcharya now getting this  'lambda_function': cannot import name '_imaging'

Comment: you don't need _imaging at all , just use object of **Image** from PIL library for the example you are following

Answer (score 2):

Even though the documentation clearly outlines the steps used to manually create the zip artifact for your lambda function. This solution is not very scalable. I've been using a very small package called [juniper](https://github.com/eabglobal/juniper) to seamlessly package python lambda functions.

In your particular case this are the steps you need to take:

Assuming this is your folder structure:

```
.
├── manifest.yml
├── src
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── lambda_function.py
```

In the requirements.txt you would include only the dependencies of your lambda function, in this case, the PIL library.

```
Pillow==6.0.0
```

Now, you just have to create a small file to tell juniper what to include in the zip file. The manifest.yml would look like:

```
functions:
  reko:
    requirements: ./src/requirements.txt.
    include:
    - ./src/lambda_function.py
```

Now you need to `pip install juniper` in your local environment. Execute the cli command:

`juni build`

Juniper will create: `./dist/reko.zip`. That file will have your source code as well as any dependency you include in your requirements.txt file.

By default juniper uses docker containers and the build command will use python3.6. You can override that default.

Comment: This took a little bit to get set up but is working great. Using python3.7+ you just have to add an additional argument, see: https://github.com/eabglobal/juniper#python37-and-beyond

Comment: There is a typo on `./src/requirements.txt.`. It shouldn't have a dot in the end of the line. It should be just `./src/requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error as PIL for Python 2.x or PILLOW for 3.x are not standard libraries available in python lambda environment.

To use such a library , you have to make a custom deployment package of all libraries you need as well as the python code you want to deploy. This package can be made easily either in **docker** or by using **EC2** instance .

here is the procedure how you will make that deployment package on **EC2** :

1. Suppose you have your file named **CreateThumbnail.py**
2. If your source code is on a local host, copy it over to EC2.

   **scp -i key.pem /path/to/my_code.py ec2-user@public-ip-address:~/CreateThumbnail.py**
3. Connect to a 64-bit Amazon Linux instance via SSH.

   **ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@public-ip-address**
4. Install Python 3.6 and virtualenv using the following steps:

   a) **sudo yum install -y gcc zlib zlib-devel openssl openssl-devel**

   b) **wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tgz**

   c) **tar -xzvf Python-3.6.1.tgz**

   d) **cd Python-3.6.1 && ./configure && make**

   e) **sudo make install**f**sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install virtualenv**
5. Choose the virtual environment that was installed via pip3

   **/usr/local/bin/virtualenv ~/shrink_venv**

   **source ~/shrink_venv/bin/activate**
6. Install libraries in the virtual environment

   **pip install Pillow**

   **pip install boto3**
7. Add the contents of lib and lib64 site-packages to your .zip file. Note that the following steps assume you used Python runtime version 3.6. If you used version 2.7 you will need to update accordingly.

   **cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages**

   **zip -r9 ~/CreateThumbnail.zip**

   note-  To include all hidden files, use the following option:

   **zip -r9 ~/CreateThumbnail.zip**
8. Add your python code to the .zip file

   **cd ~**

   **zip -g CreateThumbnail.zip CreateThumbnail.py**

Now *CreateThumbnail.zip* is your custom deployment package , just copy it to s3 and upload it to your lambda.

*This example is taken from official AWS documentation at 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html*

Comment: CreateThumbnail.py   is lambda function ?

Comment: you can give it any name , but always configure your handler in this way **filename.handler-function**  , e.g  **disco.lambda_handler** where disco.py is filename and lambda_handler is code handler module for lambda

Comment: All these installations from step 4 are on local machine or EC2 ?

Comment: Installations need to be done on EC2, from local machine the only thing you need to do is copying your python code to Ec2

Comment: still  Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_imaging'   :|

Comment: This is a direct copy and paste from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this exact same problem. There are two steps that you can take here: manual versus automated packaging and deploying.

The manual step would involve creating the correct virtualenv and install dependencies in that virtual environment. Then zip everything and upload to AWS.

To automate stuff, I always prefer to use the Serverless framework to package and deploy Lambda functions. Specifically the python-requirements-plugin helps with packaging. But I do have to specify the following things to tell the framework to build within a docker container and don't strip any libraries:

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    strip: false
```

Answer (score 0):

As most of the answers here already allude to, AWS Lambda execution environment includes only the Python built-in packages and boto3, but nothing else.

To include external packages you need to include them yourself, either by building them and including it in your function upload -- or by packagaging them as layers. Also remember that the packages themselves need to be built for Amazon Linux.

If you're using python3.7, then you can use this publicly available layer for pillow:
https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers