# Import Error: 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_imaging'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to import PIL on AWS.

I installed PIL using the below command.

`pip3 install Pillow -t  Desktop/myfolder`

then zipped inside library and a lambda_function.py

It looks on aws console like this

[EDIT :  New snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twdwj.png)

But I'm getting the below error.

ule 'lambda_function': cannot import name '_imaging'

Comment: First of all, why an image at all? Second, why an image that has a different error than the one you're asking about?

Comment: @OferSadan  that was by mistake . I updated question

Comment: this question already has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50734416/aws-lambda-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function-no-module-named-pil

Answer (score -1):

Python will not import names with a leading underscore unless the module defines an  __all __ list that overrides this behavior. Leading underscores impact how names get imported from modules.

Refer [here](https://dbader.org/blog/meaning-of-underscores-in-python) for detailed explanation.

Just do this instead

```
import PIL
```