# Exporting zipped file from docker container

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, docker-compose

I am trying to run aws lambda function with Pillow package but getting an import error. This error is like a standard error (talked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50734416/aws-lambda-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function-no-module-named-pil) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473501/getting-pil-pillow-4-2-1-to-upload-properly-to-aws-lambda-py3-6)).
What I understood from those threads is: to resolve the problem I should run the package installation in a docker container and then use that as a zip package from lambda function.

Following is my docker file:

```
FROM lambci/lambda:python3.6

USER root

ENV APP_DIR /var/task

WORKDIR $APP_DIR

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY bin ./bin
COPY lib ./lib

RUN mkdir -p $APP_DIR/lib
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt -t /var/task/lib
```

(i am using [lambci/lambda:python3.6](https://hub.docker.com/r/lambci/lambda/) to emulate python lambda environment locally and locally the lambda function runs fine).

My question is: once I run the `docker-build` command, I can see the image being build but I can't seem to figure out a way to zip the packages and dependencies (in lib and bin) installed and use that zip file to upload on s3.

Following is my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  lambda:
    build: .
    environment:
      - PYTHONPATH=/var/task/src:/var/task/lib
      - PATH=/var/task/bin
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/task/src/
```

Comment: Start a container from the image. The files will be available in it. You can also copy them to your host by mounting a volume.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the easiest way to add dependencies to a lambda function is through [lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html). The layer can be created using docker described in the [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/).

Thus you can add `pillow` to your function as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`. The layer if fully independent from your project, so it can be created in any location, e.g. in `/tmp`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of `pillow`:

```
echo pillow > ./requirements.txt
```

3. Run the following docker command:

The command will create layer for python3.6:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.6" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Archive the layer as zip:

```
zip -9 -r mylayer.zip python
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mylayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtime` to `python3.6`.
6. Add the the layer created in step 5 to your function.