# Lambda-specific package doesn't work on AWS lambda

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I downloaded [this lambda package from github](https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages/tree/master/lambda_packages) so I can run my lambda function on AWS. I didn't use all the folders, I only took the ones I needed.

So my `.zip` folder contains: `lambda_function.py`, `Pillow`, `numpy`, `OpenCV` and `psycopg2`.

I uploaded that .zip file to my lambda function. However upon testing it returns this error:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'PIL'
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error as PIL is imported in my code (the code is provided by AWS):

**lambda_function.py**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import os
import sys
import uuid
from PIL import Image
import PIL.Image

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def resize_image(image_path, resized_path):
    with Image.open(image_path) as image:
        image.thumbnail(tuple(x / 2 for x in image.size))
        image.save(resized_path)

def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key'] 
        download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
        upload_path = '/tmp/resized-{}'.format(key)

        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        resize_image(download_path, upload_path)
        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path, '{}resized'.format(bucket), key)
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Edit: The solution to the duplicate suggests creating an EC2 instance, which is not what I'm doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS lambda Unable to import module 'lambda\_function': No module named PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50734416/aws-lambda-unable-to-import-module-lambda-function-no-module-named-pil)

Comment: you have to add compiled libraries, you can make a custom package either using docker or using EC2 instance

you can follow this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50711722/how-to-upload-python-code-with-libraries-to-aws-lambda-from-windows-local-machin/50741325#50741325

Answer (score 0):

Because AWS lambda runs on the amazonlinux OS, you need to upload the packages installed on that OS. 
This repository will help.
https://github.com/hidekuma/lambda-layers-for-python-runtime