# Why will my local Python Script work perfectly but then fail as soon as I try to run in Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openpyxl

I am essentially at the point of trying to run a Hello World application because I cannot figure this out.

My local Env is Python 3.12.0. My Lambda Function is Python 3.12.0..

I have followed both methods in the official AWS documentation for creating my zip file to load to Lambda.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

The script is 100% barebones and works without error on my local PC.

Script:

```
import openpyxl
import snowflake.connector
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import sys
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

When I attempt to run this in Lambda as a simple test I get back the following log:

```
[ERROR] AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl
  File "/var/task/openpyxl/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from openpyxl.compat.numbers import NUMPY
  File "/var/task/openpyxl/compat/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .numbers import NUMERIC_TYPES
  File "/var/task/openpyxl/compat/numbers.py", line 9, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/var/task/numpy/__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    _delvewheel_patch_1_5_2()
  File "/var/task/numpy/__init__.py", line 109, in _delvewheel_patch_1_5_2
    os.add_dll_directory(libs_dir)
```

Any help would be truly appreciated as I am losing my mind over this. Note this works fine when I only installed boto3. My guess is the issue is to do with either snowflake or openpyxl. Granted the exact version are installed locally on my pc and my virtual env as I am pushing to Lambda.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a Windows version of `openpyxl` on LInux. `os.add_dll_directory()` is a Windows-only function.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Is there any way to install the Linux version of pip packages on a Windows machine?

Comment: You can run various flavors of Linux in WSL on Windows, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I think this may answer you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50711722/how-to-upload-python-code-with-libraries-to-aws-lambda-from-windows-local-machin

Comment: I think @Barmar is correct. You will need lambda layer for the lambda to run the code in lambda. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/chapter-layers.html